# How to properly write if-then lambda statement for pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, lambda, apply

I have the following code:

```
data = [[11001218, 'Value', 93483.37, 'G', '', 93483.37, '', '56117J100', 'FRA', 'Equity'], 
        [11001218, 'Value', 3572.73, 'G', 3572.73, '', '56117J100', '', 'LUM', 'Equity'], 
        [11001218, 'Value', 89910.64, 'G', 89910.64, '', '56117J100', '', 'WAR', 'Equity'],
        [11005597, 'Value', 72640313.34,'L','',72640313.34, 'REVR21964', '','IN2',  'Repo']
       ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Type', 'Diff', 'Group', 'Amount','Amount2', 'Id2', 'Id3', 'Executor', 'Name'])

def logic_builder(row, row2, row3):
    if row['Name'] == 'Repo' and row['Group'] == 'L':
        return 'Fine resultant'
    elif (row['ID'] == row2['ID']) and (row['ID'] == row3['ID']) and (row['Group'] == row2['Group']) and (row['Group'] == row3['Group']) and (row['Executor'] != row2['Executor']) and (row['Executor'] != row3['Executor']):    
        return 'Difference in Executor'

df['Results'] = df.apply(lambda row: logic_builder(row, row2, row3), axis=1)
```

If you look at the first 3 rows, they are all technically the same. They contain the same ID, Type, Group, and Name. The only difference is the executor, hence I would like my if-then statement to return "Difference in Executor". I am having trouble figuring out how to right the if-then to look at all the rows with similar attributes for the fields I mentioned above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a single row, then determine its index and look for the other rows with `df.iloc[index]`.

Here an example

```
def logic_builder(row):
    global df #you need to access the df

    i = row.name #row index

    #get next rows
    try:
        row2 = df.iloc[i+1] 
        row3 = df.iloc[i+2]
    except IndexError:
        return
    
    if row['Name'] == 'Repo' and row['Group'] == 'L':
        return 'Fine resultant'
    elif (row['ID'] == row2['ID']) and (row['ID'] == row3['ID']) and (row['Group'] == row2['Group']) and (row['Group'] == row3['Group']) and (row['Executor'] != row2['Executor']) and (row['Executor'] != row3['Executor']):    
        return 'Difference in Executor'

df['Results'] = df.apply(logic_builder, axis=1)
```

Of course, since the result depend on the next two rows, you can't run it on the last 2 rows of the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the function a bit to perform on a chunk/slice of a dataframe, based on group using `groupby` since you are performing the action per group. A modified version of the function you have written would look something like this:

```py
def logic_builder(group):
    if group['Name'].eq('Repo').all() and group['Group'].eq('L').all():
        return 'Fine resultant'
    elif group['Group'].nunique()==1 and group['Executor'].nunique()>1:    
        return 'Difference in Executor'
```

row1, row2, row3,..,rown is not going to work actually, because there may be one or more rows per group, so better strategy is to perform if else using `all`, and `nunique` (which essentially gives number of unique values in the selected column) for the above logic that you have.

Then apply the function on `groupby` object:

```py
df.groupby('ID').apply(logic_builder)
ID
11001218    Difference in Executor
11005597            Fine resultant
dtype: object
```

You can finally join above value to the actual dataframe if needed.